# error while processing rock-dkms and rocm-dkms

Tags: apt, kernel, updates

Hi guys since yesterday I have been trying to fix a problem regarding the rock-dkms and rocm-dkms, whenever i try to update or install any packages to my system this error occurs:

```
    -------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  amdgpu
Version: 3.7-20
Kernel:  5.4.0-42-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

amdgpu.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


amdttm.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


amdkcl.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


amd-sched.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


Running the post_remove script:
depmod...

update-initramfs.........

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 3.7-20
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new amdgpu-3.7-20 DKMS files...
Building for 5.4.0-42-generic 5.7.16-xanmod2
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.4.0-42-generic
  Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Done.
Forcing installation of amdgpu

amdgpu.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/updates/dkms/

amdttm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/updates/dkms/

amdkcl.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/updates/dkms/

amd-sched.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

Backing up initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic to /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic.old-
dkms
Making new initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
(If next boot fails, revert to initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic.old-dkms image)
update-initramfs.........

DKMS: install completed.
Building initial module for 5.7.16-xanmod2
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.7.16-xanmod2 is not supporte
d
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.7.16-xanmod2 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/3.7-20/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package rock-dkms (--configure):
 installed rock-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error 
exit status 10
Setting up libio-string-perl (1.08-3) ...
Setting up libcwidget4:amd64 (0.5.18-5build1) ...
Setting up aptitude-common (0.8.12-1ubuntu4) ...
Setting up aptitude (0.8.12-1ubuntu4) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/aptitude-curses to provide /usr/bin/aptitude
 (aptitude) in auto mode
Setting up libsub-name-perl (0.26-1) ...
Setting up libfcgi-perl (0.79-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rocm-dkms:
 rocm-dkms depends on rock-dkms; however:
  Package rock-dkms is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package rocm-dkms (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libclass-accessor-perl (0.51-1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
                          Setting up libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.15-1) ...
Setting up libparse-debianchangelog-perl (1.2.0-13) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rock-dkms
 rocm-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am new to the Linux environment so I am not really sure what to do, I tried to look up for a solution but nothing seemed to work :/

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by:

```
sudo apt purge linux-image-5.7.16-xanmod2 linux-headers-5.7.16-xanmod2 linux-xanmod-edge
```

Then:

```
dpkg --configure -a && apt-get update && apt-get -f install && apt-get dist-upgrade
```